# CSS - background image not showing properly

Tags: html, css

No matter what I do, I cannot get my image in the .container div to show up properly when formatting with CSS. Only the top ~10% of the image is showing. If I put the img tag in HTML it will work perfectly. But I want to format in CSS, not HTML, and in such away that it is mobile-first compatible. What I want is for the image to be centered and larger than it's currently displaying. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RABstyle.css">
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="author" content="Beth Bennett">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>
<header>

<div class="icons"><p>Icons</p></div>

<ul class = "buttons">
<button id="LogIn" type="button">Log In</button>
<button id="SignUp" type="button">Sign Up</button>
</ul>
</header>

<div class="container">
<h2 class="intro">America's source for....</h2>
<ul class="selector">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Ds</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Or</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0px;
padding:0px;
font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
background-color:#ffffE0;
}
header {
background-color: #AA0000;
height: 75px;
padding: 15px;


}
.icons{
float: left;
margin-left: 100px;
}

.buttons {
text-align: right;
margin-right: 300px;

}
.container {
background: url("HomePageImageFinal.svg") no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: 1500px 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Give us a live link to your html file where shows your background picture?

Answer (score 0):

Add `px` - it doesn't have any measurement unit now -  or `100%` to your `width` and `height` attributes (depending on your needs)

I added a `background-size:cover` to your code and it worked, with another image, because you didn't provide the SVG:

```
.container {
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/") no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position: center top;
height: 2000px;
width: 2000px;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0y5e73rr/)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I had to resize height: 1500px and width: 1000px. And what happened? It made it the size I wanted, but it left justified it. So now, it's no longer in the center.

Comment: Can you provide the image? It seems that it's just a matter of setting the right `background-position`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
background-size: 100% 100%; or
background-size: contain; or
background-size: cover;
```

depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Also, if you have floats inside your container than you need to clear these. The container won't have any height with floating elements inside. Unless you specify a fixed height of course.